# Can't get id from model in java(spring)

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

There is a model Reader:

```
public class Reader {
    private int id;

    @NotEmpty(message = "Name shouldn't be empty!")
    @Size(min = 2, max = 100, message = "Name should be between 2 and 100 characters!")
    private Stringname;

    @Min(value = 0, message = "Age should be greater than 0!")
    private int age;

    public Reader(int id, String name, int age) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public Reader(){}

   // getters and setters...
}
```

And also dao ReaderDao:

```
@Component
public class ReaderDao {
    private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public ReaderDao(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }
    public Reader getReader(int id){
        return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT * FROM reader WHERE reader_id=?",
                new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(Reader.class), id);
    }
}
```

I am using the getReader method in the ReaderController:

```
@GetMapping("/{id}")
    public String readerPage(@PathVariable("id") int id,
                             Model model){
        model.addAttribute("reader", readerDao.getReader(id));
        Reader reader = (Reader) model.getAttribute("reader");
        System.out.println(reader.getId()); // always outputs 0
        return "readers/profile";
    }
```

And on the line with System.out.println it always outputs 0, there is also a method where all readers are taken and there also all id is 0, how to deal with it?

Comment: How are you adding `Reader` entries to the database? Are you explicitly setting the id before you save the entity?

Comment: if we pass wrong id it will throw org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException: Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 0 . Please check the data in the database  and try to log  pathvariable id